# Width CSS Transition on Page Load

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I know this probably cannot be done without javascript but I dont mind using it.

I have a div that grabs the width percentage with PHP.

All I need to do is that on page load I would like the bar ( Div ) to start at 0px width and transition to the correct width percentage.

I can do it fine of course on a Hover or Active state but cant seem to get it right with page load.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use jQuery? Theres a built-in document ready function. Inside of that, add a class to the div. Then in your CSS you can style the two different states of the div to accommodate the transition

Javascipt

```
$(function(){
    $('.bar').addClass('.ready');
});
```

CSS

```
.bar {
    width: 0;
    transition: width 500ms;
}
.bar.ready {
    width: 100%;
}
```